# WampServer And Port Forwarding For External Access

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, wamp

I am trying to make my WampServer public but nothing i have tried so far seems to be working.
It was all good and well before i got a new router from my new provider.

The router is a Huawei HG523a & my ISP is TALKTALK.

These are the settings i have for the port forwarding. Advanced->Advanced->NAT->Port Mapping

```
Mapping Name: WebServer(HTTP)
Interface: nas_0_38
Protocol: TCP
Remote Host:
External Start Port: 80
External end Port: 80
Internal Port: 80
Internal Host: 192.168.1.2
Enable: Enable
```

I have reserved the IP address 192.168.1.2 for my computer under Advanced->Basic->LAN->(Ip address Reserve).

I believe this is all i need to do for the router side of things.

Now for Apache: The .httpd file...

```
Listen 192.168.1.2:80
```

And that's everything. The problem is that when i put in my public IP address its not forwarding to my WampServer. its just going to the routers log-in page. If i put in my local ip then i get my servers webpage like i should. What am i missing!?

Any help would be great!
Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Did you check to see that your computer actually has the ip you reserved for it on the router?

Comment: yea i used cmd->ipconfig and it was correct

Comment: You could try changing your `.httpd` to just `Listen 80` to make it listen on all interfaces. That's really just a stab in the dark though.

Comment: Yes no luck there :/

Comment: are there no other settings in the `.httpd` file that could be stopping it?

Comment: But the server works, right? If the server works from within the network, then it is probably not a server problem, but something with the router like you said.

Comment: Yea server works fine..I Think :L I can access it using my local ip and see my web pages if that's what you mean by working? I emailed talktalk and they just sent me to PortForward.com :/ no help at all

Comment: Also i had portfowarding set up on my old router just fine so it must be to do with the router or the ISP

Comment: You might possibly need to add `ServerName your.public.ip:80`. I don't have any other ideas, someone with more experience will probably be able to answer this question better.

Comment: Actually, I had another idea, since you said that the router displayed a login page instead of your site, maybe it doesn't allow you to forward port 80 and you will have to use another port instead.

Comment: This sounds like the same problem: http://talktalkmembers.com/forums/showthread.php?p=921022

Comment: i cant use my public ip because its not static. i use no-ip to track it. and what other port could i use?

Comment: It would best to use port 8080 as that is the secondary http port.

Comment: okay thanks i will give it a go to morrow. but the link you sent me seemed to confirm what i thought. that the router doesn't seem to support Nat loop-back. this thread here http://talktalkmembers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=87820 seems to have the most info.

Comment: They also say that you can access the server from outside your local network? i will have to give that a try.. Will Post back tomorrow some time.

Comment: That does sound like your problem (and solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Router is the problem here. From what i have read and tested the router does not support `NAT Loop back`. This means that you can view your server using your public IP address only if you are outside of your own local network I.E (Not connected to your router). The router does support local Loop back which is why you can access the server from your local IP address.

Simply put: You/I need to get a different router which supports `NAT Loop Back`.

This means that there is nothing wrong with the port forwarding settings shown above.